# How to test within Azure - Azure Resource Manager (ARM Templates)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azureportal

Assume we have a Checkpoint Firewall Template created on Azure Portal. Is there a way to test the Template within Azure? Also if the Template is modified, is there a way to Test that new modified Template within Azure?

Answer (score 2):

You can test an ARM Template by using it in a deployment.  You can also use the `what-if` setting to produce hypothetical output without actually deploying anything.

[Microsoft Azure Docs for What-If](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell#what-if-commands)

To create a What-If deployment you can proceed a number of ways; Azure CLI, PowerShell, REST, etc.  Here is an example using REST (Postman).

Use the endpoint

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/{deploymentName}/whatIf?api-version=2020-06-01
```

Provide a body payload:

```
{
  "location": "westus2",
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "parameters": {},
    "template": {}
  }
}
```

Add your template and parameters. Supply a bearer token for authentication and deploy.

You can check the [Azure What-If REST API docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/deployments/whatif).